# java.lang.AssertionError at org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.run(WebSocketClient.java:190)

Tags: java, android, websocket

I am using WebSocketClient class to get the data from websocket in my android app but when anything change in Internet connection ( Disconnect from Internet ) it gives the following error in `WebSocketClient.java` file

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=10
APP_VERSION_NAME=0.0.1
BRAND=google
PHONE_MODEL=Android SDK built for x86_64
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.AssertionError
at org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.run(WebSocketClient.java:190)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

But the `WebSocketClient.java` is read only file it is coming from `java-websocket-1.3.0.jar` file

WebSocketClient.java

```
package org.java_websocket.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.ByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException;
import java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.java_websocket.SocketChannelIOHelper;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocketAdapter;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocketFactory;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl;
import org.java_websocket.WrappedByteChannel;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket.READYSTATE;
import org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft;
import org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_10;
import org.java_websocket.exceptions.InvalidHandshakeException;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.HandshakeImpl1Client;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.Handshakedata;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

public abstract class WebSocketClient extends WebSocketAdapter implements Runnable {
    protected URI uri;
    private WebSocketImpl conn;
    private SocketChannel channel;
    private ByteChannel wrappedchannel;
    private Thread writethread;
    private Thread readthread;
    private Draft draft;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private CountDownLatch connectLatch;
    private CountDownLatch closeLatch;
    private int timeout;
    private WebSocketClient.WebSocketClientFactory wsfactory;
    private InetSocketAddress proxyAddress;

    public WebSocketClient(URI serverURI) {
        this(serverURI, new Draft_10());
    }

    public WebSocketClient(URI serverUri, Draft draft) {
        this(serverUri, draft, (Map)null, 0);
    }

    public WebSocketClient(URI serverUri, Draft draft, Map<String, String> headers, int connecttimeout) {
        this.uri = null;
        this.conn = null;
        this.channel = null;
        this.wrappedchannel = null;
        this.connectLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        this.closeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        this.timeout = 0;
        this.wsfactory = new DefaultWebSocketClientFactory(this);
        this.proxyAddress = null;
        if (serverUri == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (draft == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null as draft is permitted for `WebSocketServer` only!");
        } else {
            this.uri = serverUri;
            this.draft = draft;
            this.headers = headers;
            this.timeout = connecttimeout;

            try {
                this.channel = SelectorProvider.provider().openSocketChannel();
                this.channel.configureBlocking(true);
            } catch (IOException var6) {
                this.channel = null;
                this.onWebsocketError((WebSocket)null, var6);
            }

            if (this.channel == null) {
                this.conn = (WebSocketImpl)this.wsfactory.createWebSocket(this, draft, (Socket)null);
                this.conn.close(-1, "Failed to create or configure SocketChannel.");
            } else {
                this.conn = (WebSocketImpl)this.wsfactory.createWebSocket(this, draft, this.channel.socket());
            }

        }
    }

    public URI getURI() {
        return this.uri;
    }

    public Draft getDraft() {
        return this.draft;
    }

    public void connect() {
        if (this.writethread != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("WebSocketClient objects are not reuseable");
        } else {
            this.writethread = new Thread(this);
            this.writethread.start();
        }
    }

    public boolean connectBlocking() throws InterruptedException {
        this.connect();
        this.connectLatch.await();
        return this.conn.isOpen();
    }

    public void close() {
        if (this.writethread != null) {
            this.conn.close(1000);
        }

    }

    public void closeBlocking() throws InterruptedException {
        this.close();
        this.closeLatch.await();
    }

    public void send(String text) throws NotYetConnectedException {
        this.conn.send(text);
    }

    public void send(byte[] data) throws NotYetConnectedException {
        this.conn.send(data);
    }

    public void run() {
        if (this.writethread == null) {
            this.writethread = Thread.currentThread();
        }

        this.interruptableRun();

        assert !this.channel.isOpen();

    }

    private final void interruptableRun() {
        if (this.channel != null) {
            try {
                String host;
                int port;
                if (this.proxyAddress != null) {
                    host = this.proxyAddress.getHostName();
                    port = this.proxyAddress.getPort();
                } else {
                    host = this.uri.getHost();
                    port = this.getPort();
                }

                this.channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
                this.conn.channel = this.wrappedchannel = this.createProxyChannel(this.wsfactory.wrapChannel(this.channel, (SelectionKey)null, host, port));
                this.timeout = 0;
                this.sendHandshake();
                this.readthread = new Thread(new WebSocketClient.WebsocketWriteThread());
                this.readthread.start();
            } catch (ClosedByInterruptException var3) {
                this.onWebsocketError((WebSocket)null, var3);
                return;
            } catch (Exception var4) {
                this.onWebsocketError(this.conn, var4);
                this.conn.closeConnection(-1, var4.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(WebSocketImpl.RCVBUF);

            try {
                while(this.channel.isOpen()) {
                    if (SocketChannelIOHelper.read(buff, this.conn, this.wrappedchannel)) {
                        this.conn.decode(buff);
                    } else {
                        this.conn.eot();
                    }

                    if (this.wrappedchannel instanceof WrappedByteChannel) {
                        WrappedByteChannel w = (WrappedByteChannel)this.wrappedchannel;
                        if (w.isNeedRead()) {
                            while(SocketChannelIOHelper.readMore(buff, this.conn, w)) {
                                this.conn.decode(buff);
                            }

                            this.conn.decode(buff);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (CancelledKeyException var5) {
                this.conn.eot();
            } catch (IOException var6) {
                this.conn.eot();
            } catch (RuntimeException var7) {
                this.onError(var7);
                this.conn.closeConnection(1006, var7.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

    private int getPort() {
        int port = this.uri.getPort();
        if (port == -1) {
            String scheme = this.uri.getScheme();
            if (scheme.equals("wss")) {
                return 443;
            } else if (scheme.equals("ws")) {
                return 80;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("unkonow scheme" + scheme);
            }
        } else {
            return port;
        }
    }

    private void sendHandshake() throws InvalidHandshakeException {
        String part1 = this.uri.getPath();
        String part2 = this.uri.getQuery();
        String path;
        if (part1 != null && part1.length() != 0) {
            path = part1;
        } else {
            path = "/";
        }

        if (part2 != null) {
            path = path + "?" + part2;
        }

        int port = this.getPort();
        String host = this.uri.getHost() + (port != 80 ? ":" + port : "");
        HandshakeImpl1Client handshake = new HandshakeImpl1Client();
        handshake.setResourceDescriptor(path);
        handshake.put("Host", host);
        if (this.headers != null) {
            Iterator i$ = this.headers.entrySet().iterator();

            while(i$.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, String> kv = (Entry)i$.next();
                handshake.put((String)kv.getKey(), (String)kv.getValue());
            }
        }

        this.conn.startHandshake(handshake);
    }

    public READYSTATE getReadyState() {
        return this.conn.getReadyState();
    }

    public final void onWebsocketMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
        this.onMessage(message);
    }

    public final void onWebsocketMessage(WebSocket conn, ByteBuffer blob) {
        this.onMessage(blob);
    }

    public final void onWebsocketOpen(WebSocket conn, Handshakedata handshake) {
        this.connectLatch.countDown();
        this.onOpen((ServerHandshake)handshake);
    }

    public final void onWebsocketClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
        this.connectLatch.countDown();
        this.closeLatch.countDown();
        if (this.readthread != null) {
            this.readthread.interrupt();
        }

        this.onClose(code, reason, remote);
    }

    public final void onWebsocketError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
        this.onError(ex);
    }

    public final void onWriteDemand(WebSocket conn) {
    }

    public void onWebsocketCloseInitiated(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason) {
        this.onCloseInitiated(code, reason);
    }

    public void onWebsocketClosing(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
        this.onClosing(code, reason, remote);
    }

    public void onCloseInitiated(int code, String reason) {
    }

    public void onClosing(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
    }

    public WebSocket getConnection() {
        return this.conn;
    }

    public final void setWebSocketFactory(WebSocketClient.WebSocketClientFactory wsf) {
        this.wsfactory = wsf;
    }

    public final WebSocketFactory getWebSocketFactory() {
        return this.wsfactory;
    }

    public InetSocketAddress getLocalSocketAddress(WebSocket conn) {
        return this.channel != null ? (InetSocketAddress)this.channel.socket().getLocalSocketAddress() : null;
    }

    public InetSocketAddress getRemoteSocketAddress(WebSocket conn) {
        return this.channel != null ? (InetSocketAddress)this.channel.socket().getLocalSocketAddress() : null;
    }

    public abstract void onOpen(ServerHandshake var1);

    public abstract void onMessage(String var1);

    public abstract void onClose(int var1, String var2, boolean var3);

    public abstract void onError(Exception var1);

    public void onMessage(ByteBuffer bytes) {
    }

    public ByteChannel createProxyChannel(ByteChannel towrap) {
        return (ByteChannel)(this.proxyAddress != null ? new WebSocketClient.DefaultClientProxyChannel(towrap) : towrap);
    }

    public void setProxy(InetSocketAddress proxyaddress) {
        this.proxyAddress = proxyaddress;
    }

    private class WebsocketWriteThread implements Runnable {
        private WebsocketWriteThread() {
        }

        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("WebsocketWriteThread");

            try {
                while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    SocketChannelIOHelper.writeBlocking(WebSocketClient.this.conn, WebSocketClient.this.wrappedchannel);
                }
            } catch (IOException var2) {
                WebSocketClient.this.conn.eot();
            } catch (InterruptedException var3) {
            }

        }
    }

    public interface WebSocketClientFactory extends WebSocketFactory {
        ByteChannel wrapChannel(SocketChannel var1, SelectionKey var2, String var3, int var4) throws IOException;
    }

    public class DefaultClientProxyChannel extends AbstractClientProxyChannel {
        public DefaultClientProxyChannel(ByteChannel towrap) {
            super(towrap);
        }

        public String buildHandShake() {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            String host = WebSocketClient.this.uri.getHost();
            b.append("CONNECT ");
            b.append(host);
            b.append(":");
            b.append(WebSocketClient.this.getPort());
            b.append(" HTTP/1.1\n");
            b.append("Host: ");
            b.append(host);
            b.append("\n");
            return b.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the assert is false, meaning the connection is still open. You could close it in a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

The third-party library has a description. You can write a class to inherit the WebSocketClient class and rewrite the code after network disconnection and reconnection. The code example of the third-party library is provided for reference.
[image]